# What is the word for "able to recognize something through limitations placed on you"

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

For example, you see a small part of a curtain picture, but from this small part you are able to recognize that this is a "curtain".

Or if your sight is hazy, and you can recognize an object because of its general outline.

My thoughts were on "make out", "discern", or "differentiate". But the last 2 sound more like "recognize from a group of similar looking objects".

So, what's the best word for above case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could **make out** that it was a curtain.

That suggests that enough of the thing's appearance was discernible to enable you to determine what it was.

**make out** would be synonymous with **discern** there.

But **differentiate** refers to the ability to distinguish one thing from another.

> We were able to differentiate the good turbine blades from the cracked ones using ultrasound.

Comment: So, let's say you have a clothing in your face, limiting your vision, and you could only see a speck of ceiling, would it be more like "I could make out a speck of ceiling" or "I discerned a speck of ceiling"?

Comment: There we are getting into the question of "register".  "A speck of ceiling" is a kind of exaggeration, a figure of speech, since a "speck" is only about the size of a poppy seed.  Given the conversational nature of such exaggerations, I would choose **make out** there because it is conversational, whereas **discern**  could be used in formal contexts.